Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<EventsPageProps, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'
Here is my code:
import EventsContainer from "@/components/events/events-container/EventsContainer"; // Main container component

interface EventProps {
  events: any[];
  pastEvents: any[];
}

const EventsPage: React.FC<EventProps> = ({ events, pastEvents }) => {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto bg-background text-foreground shadow-md rounded-lg p-6">
      <EventsContainer events={events} pastEvents={pastEvents} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EventsPage;

But each time I build the nextjs project, I get this error message:
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<EventProps, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint
'{ [x: string]: never; }'.
The above file is the page.tsx file of my events component.
I don't know what to do because here is the code of the page.tsx of my about component and it is perfectly fine:
import AboutContainer from "@/components/about/about-container/AboutContainer";

const AboutPage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto bg-background text-foreground shadow-md rounded-lg p-6">
      <AboutContainer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AboutPage;

I don't get why the other gives an issue.

Typescript is smart enough to infer whether something is a React component so typing a component as React.FC shouldn't be needed.
As for passing the props type, you can refactor your component to be this and it should be happy:
interface EventProps {
  events: any[];
  pastEvents: any[];
}

const EventsPage = ({ events, pastEvents }: EventProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto bg-background text-foreground shadow-md rounded-lg p-6">
      <EventsContainer events={events} pastEvents={pastEvents} />
    </div>
  );
};


Didn't really work. still getting the same error

Can you create a reproducible example in a code sandbox?

I finally did resolve the error @Boocher. Thanks though for your effort. I changed the code totally. and I noticed the error was from the datatype of the EventProps
